# How to parse a String YYYYMMDD_HHMMSSZ in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I need to parse a UTC date and time string, e.g. 20180531_132001Z into a Java 8 date and time object. How do I go about doing this using Java 8's new date and time libraries? Most examples I see is for LocalDateTime, like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'Z'");
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("20180531_132001Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(localDateTime);
    System.out.println(localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

The code outputs:

```
2018-05-31T13:20:01
2018-05-31T13:20:01Z
```

- Is this considered local time or UTC time? The string value I am parsing is based on UTC, so I am wondering if I need to do anything further before persisting to the database.
- If the former, how do I convert that to UTC date and time?

I ultimately need to persist this to a SQL Server database table (column type is `[datetime2](7)`, using [Spring] JDBC.

**Update:** Based on the comments and answers, I think my question is not well thought out. Putting it another way, if I get an input string and I parse it without factoring any zone or offset, I will get a `LocalDateTime` object. How do I take that object and convert the encapsulated value to UTC date and time?

Comment: If you've found examples, what have you tried? Is there something you don't understand in the examples?

Comment: have you looked at `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the new packages, so I am continuing to explore

Comment: If you want consistency, used `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @rustyx the "Z" is fixed in that location of the input string.

Comment: In that case your solution is OK. `LocalDateTime` captures no time zone info. You can interpret it as UTC with `.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` like you did.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the *wrong* class for your input, lacking any concept of zone/offset. Use `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` instead.

Answer (score 9):

`LocalDateTime` can be misleading. It doesn't represent ***your*** local date/time, it represents ***a*** local date/time.
 It carries no time zone info at all.
That is, it just says for example "it's 13:20". It doesn't say *where* it's 13:20. It's up to you to interpret the *where* part.

Due to this `LocalDateTime` is usually not very useful for carrying timestamps, it's only useful for situations when the timezone is dependent on some context.<sup>1</sup>

When working with timestamps it's better to use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` instead. These carry the date, time and offset.

So `localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` will actually return an instance of `OffsetDateTime`, by interpreting `localDateTime` as UTC time.

One could argue that you can avoid the *interpreting* part by parsing with the timezone info in the first place (even though it's always `Z`):

```
    String example = "20180531_132001Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssX");
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(example, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime); // look ma, no hardcoded UTC
```

Will print:

```
2018-05-31T13:20:01Z
```

The added value is that your code automatically supports timezones (e.g. `"20180531_132001+05"`).

JDBC 4.2 compliant driver may be able to directly address java.time types by calling [`setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-).

For older JDBC drivers you can convert `dateTime` to a `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date`:

```
java.sql.Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());
java.util.Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There is almost always some *context* in which `LocalDateTime` operates. For example "*Flight KL1302 arrives at airport X tomorrow at 13:20*". Here the context of "*tomorrow at 13:20*" is the local time at airport X; it can be determined by looking up the time zone of X.

Comment: Correct Answer, but the “more useful for printing the date/time to the user” part is misleading. If you want to generate a String representing a ZonedDateTime while omitting the offset/zone information, use a `DateTimeFormatter` for that. No need to create a `LocalDateTime` object for that purpose alone. Doing so makes your code harder to read, as that is not at all the intended purpose of  `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(   // Pass java.time objects directly to database, as of JDBC 4.2.
    … ,                          // Indicate which placeholder in your SQL statement text.
    OffsetDateTime.parse(        // Parse input string as a `OffsetDateTime` as it indicates an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.
        "20180531_132001Z" ,     // Define a formatting pattern to match your particular input.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd_HHmmssX" )  // TIP: When exchanging date-time values as text, use use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than inventing your own.
    )                            // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                 // Returns a `Instant` object, always in UTC by definition.
)
```

## Details

There is some helpful information in the other Answers, but all of them have some misinformation which I tried to correct by posting comments.

Most importantly, your code is using the wrong Java class and the wrong database data type for that given input.

Below is explanation along with a complete code example, using the modern *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2 or later.

### `Z` = UTC

> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'Z'")

Never put single-quotes around vital parts of your input such as you did here with `Z`. That `Z` means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and is pronounced “Zulu”. It tells us the text of the date and time-of-day should be interpreted as using the wall-clock time of UTC rather than, say, `America/Montreal` or `Pacific/Auckland` time zones.

**Do *not* use the `LocalDateTime` for such inputs.** That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, this class does *not* represent a moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` represents the set of *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (across all time zones). Use `LocalDateTime` when you mean *any* or *all* time zones rather than one particular zone/offset. In contrast, the `Z` tells us this input uses the wall-clock time of UTC specifically.

### Parsing

Define a formatting pattern to match all important parts of your input string.

```
String input = "20180531_132001Z" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd_HHmmssX" ) ;
```

By the way, whenever possible, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than a custom format as seen in your Question. Those formats are wisely designed to be easy to parse by machine and easy to read by humans across cultures while eliminating ambiguity.

Parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) because your input indicates an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (of zero hours). An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours and minutes, nothing more, nothing less.

Use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class only if the input string indicates a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone has a `Contintent/Region` name such as `Africa/Tunis`. A zone represents the history of past, present, and future changes in the offset used by the people of a particular region.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-05-31T13:20:01Z

### Database

To communicate this moment to a database using [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later, we can directly pass the *java.time* object.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) does not accept the `OffsetDateTime`, extract the simpler class `Instant`. An `Instant` is in UTC always, by definition.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

#### Beware - Wrong datatype in your database

I am not a MS SQL Server user, but according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the column data type `DATETIME2` is not appropriate to your input. That data type seems to be equivalent to the SQL-standard type `DATETIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Such a type should never be used when recording a specific moment in history.

Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, that column type should only be used for three situations:

- The **zone or offset is unknown**.
  This is bad. This is faulty data. Analogous to having a price/cost without knowing the currency. You should be rejecting such data, not storing it.
- The **intention is “everywhere”**, as in, every time zone.
  Example, a corporate policy that states “All our factories will break for lunch at 12:30" means the factory in Delhi will break hours before the factory in Düsseldorf which breaks hours before the factory in Detroit.
- A specific moment in the future is intended, but we are **afraid of politicians redefining the time zone**.
  Governments change the rules of their time zones with surprising frequency and with surprisingly little warning (even [no warning at all][10]). So if you want to book an appointment at 3 PM on a certain date, and you really mean 3 PM regardless of any crazy decision a government might make in the interim, then store a `LocalDateTime`. To print a report or display a calendar, dynamically apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to generate a specific moment (`ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`). This must be done on-the-fly rather than storing the value.

Since your input is a specific moment, a certain point on the timeline, you should be storing it in the database using a column type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Wow... I can save a couple days of searching online and in books just by going through the information packed in your answer. Totally worth the read, maybe tl;dr for others but not to me. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, I am parsing with `OffsetDateTime` and using the same data type in my POJO. I am using `datetimeoffset(7)` as the database column type. I am still some troubles which are implementation specific and it made sense to ask a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693048/unable-to-insert-datetimeoffset-value-using-spring-boot-on-sql-server-2016) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick to parse string to LocalDateTime :

```
    String example = "20180531_132001Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssX");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(example, formatter);
```

See that [code run live in IdeOne.com.](https://www.ideone.com/unGFKk)

> dateTime.toString(): 2018-05-31T13:20:01Z

```
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(dateTime.toInstant());
```

Timestamp then is saved into db

Comment: This is a wrong answer. It is throwing `Text '20180531_132001Z' could not be parsed at index 15`

Comment: Correct date format string (based on example code in my question is `"yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'Z'"`. That works for me. You need to single-quote the "Z".

Comment: edited answer. Z in example string means zero so X pattern should do the trick ;)

Comment: This is almost a correct solution, only you should use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` when parsing a timezone.

Comment: from what I understood Z in string means zero offset so no offset at all .
so then when putting it in db sql timestamp. it would look like Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);

Comment: But if you parse `20180531_132001+01` the result will be wrong.

Comment: agreed. didnt take into consideration other strings that are applied to my pattern

Comment: @WebUser Wrong advice - Putting single-quote marks around the `Z` means to ignore that input entirely. That would be ignoring vital information, the fact that this date-time uses the wall-clock time of UTC. [The `Z` means UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones), and is pronounced “Zulu”, also known as “Zulu" time.

Comment: Good Answer, except no need to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp` again. As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* types with a database. `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , dateTime.toInstant() ) ;`

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for correcting me and providing the clarification on use of `Z` as well as using `java.time` with a database. I am using MS SQL JDBC drivers 6.x which should be JDBC 4.2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
   OffsetDateTime utc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
   System.out.println(utc.toString());
   DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy mm dd  hh:mm a");
   System.out.println(utc.format(format));
}
```

Comment: I am trying to parse, not generate a date time string value.

Comment: Did you try convert to java.sql.Date before send to DB?

Comment: @RodolfoTVA The `java.sql.Date` class is legacy, supplanted years ago by the *java.time.LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly can use LocalDateTime and format it to look like a zoned date time using offset, it would be easier to use an Object designed to store time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("20180531_132001Z", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyMMdd_HHmmssX"));
```

This gives you the option to use Instant to convert to SQL timestamp or any other format without having to hard-code the time zone, especially if time zone is added in the future or changes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

You can view the timestamp's instant and compare it to the toString, which should be pegged to your timezone, and instant.toString, which pegs to UTC.

```
System.out.print(timestamp + " " + timestamp.toInstant().toString());
```

Comment: The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is badly-designed, troublesome, and now “legacy”. Avoid it. No need to use that class ever again as of JDBC 4.2 and later. The generate a `String` representing a `ZonedDateTime`, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) – that is its very purpose.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is not the appropriate class here, as the input lacks a time zone. For an input indicating only an offset-from-UTC (or UTC itself) rather than a full time zone, use `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` classes.